# Why does tfs prompt me to overwrite every file?

Tags: tfs

Why does tfs prompt me to overwrite every file?

Comment: a little more context please...

Comment: and more tagging please.

Comment: When I open any file in my solution and I make some changes and try to save the file, TFS says the file cannot be saved because it is write-protected. It then gives me some options, one of them being to Overwrite the file.

Comment: You didn't check out the file?

Comment: Ensure that you are bound to source control.

Comment: @Joe - Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions typically begin with a capital letter and sport at least one question mark. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: @Ewald: Thanks for this hint. Yesterday the network was down and I couldn't reach my project in TFS. Today I've been suddenly prompted to overwrite write-protected files I've forgotten the incidence and I wondered. Then I discovered that Source-Control was off-line, thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To work under TFS source control, you will need the following:

- Your solution must be in source control!
- Your source control provider must be set to TFS. Tools > Options > Source Control and make sure it's the default SC provider.
- You must have a workspace mapping on your local drive that tells TFS where the solution should be located on your hard drive. Open Source Control and there is a drop-down list at the top of the window that shows the currently selected workspace. Drop this combo-box down and it gives an option to edit the workspace, where you can tell TFS where specific folders in its hierarchy are to be located on your hard drive.
- You need to bind the solution to source control to tell TFS that you want to work in a source controlled way on this solution. (From memory) go to  File > Source Control > Change Source Control  and usually just clicking the "Bind" button is enough.
- You may need to synchronise your PC with the server. Open the source control window, right click on the parent folder of the solution, and do a "Get Specific Version". Set this to "Latest" and tick the checkbox to get files that the source control system thinks you already have. This will synchronise your PC with the network so TFS knows what's going on. (Note: The other checkbox will cause TFS to overwrite writable files, which could mean you lose any local changes you have made, so take a backup of your code first, and be careful about which options you enable)

I've been a bit brief, but if you find you need to do any of the above, I should have given you enough info that you can search the web for more specific help.

Comment: In VS2013 menu: File > Source Control > Go Online